Intel Wi-fi Adaptor intermittently becomes very slow and/or disconnects
MSI Raider GE76 12UE 
Intel Corporation Alder Lake-P PCH CNVi WiFi (rev 01) 
Ubuntu 22.04.4
I'm experiencing frequent issues with my wi-fi that causes my internet to become very slow/it disconnects completetly, sometimes these "crashes" can last only a few seconds but never longer than a minute, then my internet reconnects.
I noticed it about 2 weeks ago and I think it is progressively becoming worse. My colleague works about 3 meters away in an adjacent room and experiences no issue with their wifi.
System packages are up to date.
Here is the relevant logs from my wifi
19:42:25 kernel: r8169 0000:30:00.0 enp48s0: Link is Down
19:42:18 kernel: i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] *ERROR* Atomic update failure on pipe A (start=465223 end=465224) time 218 us, min 1062, max 1079, scanline start 1056, end 1093
19:42:14 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: RFIm is deactivated, reason = 5
19:42:13 kernel: ieee80211 phy0: Hardware restart was requested
19:42:13 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Collecting data: ini trigger 4 fired (delay=0ms).
19:41:57 kernel: ieee80211 phy0: Hardware restart was requested
19:41:57 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Collecting data: ini trigger 4 fired (delay=0ms).
19:41:15 kernel: ieee80211 phy0: Hardware restart was requested
19:41:15 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Collecting data: ini trigger 4 fired (delay=0ms).
19:40:42 kernel: i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] *ERROR* Atomic update failure on pipe C (start=179690 end=179691) time 212 us, min 1431, max 1439, scanline start 1422, end 1440
19:40:13 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: RFIm is deactivated, reason = 5
19:40:12 kernel: ieee80211 phy0: Hardware restart was requested
19:40:12 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Collecting data: ini trigger 4 fired (delay=0ms).
19:39:57 kernel: ieee80211 phy0: Hardware restart was requested
19:39:57 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Collecting data: ini trigger 4 fired (delay=0ms).
19:39:15 kernel: ieee80211 phy0: Hardware restart was requested
19:39:15 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Collecting data: ini trigger 4 fired (delay=0ms).
19:37:15 kernel: ieee80211 phy0: Hardware restart was requested
19:37:15 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Collecting data: ini trigger 4 fired (delay=0ms).
19:36:57 kernel: ieee80211 phy0: Hardware restart was requested
19:36:57 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Collecting data: ini trigger 4 fired (delay=0ms).
19:36:10 kernel: ieee80211 phy0: Hardware restart was requested
19:36:10 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Collecting data: ini trigger 4 fired (delay=0ms).
19:35:30 kernel: i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] *ERROR* Atomic update failure on pipe A (start=406510 end=406511) time 204 us, min 1062, max 1079, scanline start 1060, end 1095
19:35:16 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: RFIm is deactivated, reason = 5
19:35:15 kernel: ieee80211 phy0: Hardware restart was requested
19:35:15 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Collecting data: ini trigger 4 fired (delay=0ms).
19:35:07 kernel: i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] *ERROR* Atomic update failure on pipe C (start=159616 end=159617) time 219 us, min 1431, max 1439, scanline start 1429, end 1448
19:34:25 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: RFIm is deactivated, reason = 5
19:34:24 kernel: ieee80211 phy0: Hardware restart was requested
19:34:24 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Collecting data: ini trigger 4 fired (delay=0ms).
19:34:05 kernel: i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] *ERROR* Atomic update failure on pipe C (start=155909 end=155910) time 191 us, min 1431, max 1439, scanline start 1429, end 1445
19:33:27 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: RFIm is deactivated, reason = 5
19:33:27 kernel: ieee80211 phy0: Hardware restart was requested
19:33:27 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Collecting data: ini trigger 4 fired (delay=0ms).
19:33:03 kernel: i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] *ERROR* Atomic update failure on pipe C (start=152197 end=152198) time 202 us, min 1431, max 1439, scanline start 1424, end 1442
19:32:49 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: RFIm is deactivated, reason = 5
19:32:49 kernel: ieee80211 phy0: Hardware restart was requested
19:32:49 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Collecting data: ini trigger 4 fired (delay=0ms).
19:32:12 kernel: ieee80211 phy0: Hardware restart was requested
19:32:12 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Collecting data: ini trigger 4 fired (delay=0ms).
19:31:15 kernel: ieee80211 phy0: Hardware restart was requested
19:31:15 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Collecting data: ini trigger 4 fired (delay=0ms).
19:30:41 kernel: i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] *ERROR* Atomic update failure on pipe C (start=143651 end=143652) time 218 us, min 1431, max 1439, scanline start 1422, end 1441
19:30:27 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: RFIm is deactivated, reason = 5
19:30:27 kernel: ieee80211 phy0: Hardware restart was requested
19:30:27 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Collecting data: ini trigger 4 fired (delay=0ms).
19:30:10 kernel: i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] *ERROR* Atomic update failure on pipe C (start=141793 end=141794) time 195 us, min 1431, max 1439, scanline start 1428, end 1445
19:29:16 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: RFIm is deactivated, reason = 5
19:29:15 kernel: ieee80211 phy0: Hardware restart was requested
19:29:15 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Collecting data: ini trigger 4 fired (delay=0ms).

Things I've tried:
Switching wireless networks - from 2.4ghz to 5ghz on the same network and also to another router on the same network - no changes
Internet hotspot from mobile via USB tethering - Connection was still bad
Wired connection from router used as wireless extender - Internet works great!
I asked around chatGPT for a while and it says firmware or hardware but who knows!
